# Sklearn - scaler.fit_transform - ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a task to create a 30x40 feature matrix with random integers between 1 & 100:

```
import numpy as np
matrix= np.random.randint(1,100,size=(30,40))
```

Next I need to rescale the elements in the matrix to be between the range 5-10:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit (5,10)
matrix1 = scaler.fit_transform(matrix)
```

Which gives me this error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=5.0.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample
```

I've tried reshaping the data:

```
matrix.reshape(-1,1)
```

but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define the feature range when you create an instance of MinMaxScaler like this:

```
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(5, 10))
```

And then you could fit and transform the data like this:

```
matrix1 = scaler.fit_transform(matrix)
```

The last line is a short form for:

```
scaler.fit(matrix)
matrix1 = scaler.transform(matrix)
```